# Why is the amplitude of EM waves constant?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Most of the pictures I see on the internet on electromagnetic waves, show two prependicular constant sinusoidal waves made of electric and magnetic fields. Shouldn't the magnitude of at least the electric field decrease as distance increases by the inverse square law? It is as if you would feel the same electric force even if you are millions of light years away from the source charge assuming you are a point charge with no dimensions.

Comment: Some people say it is the intensity which is decreasing with distance. Is intensity meaningful for a point particle occupying no volume and having no surface?

Comment: This question is about some illustration.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the amplitude should decrease with the distance from the source but when you are very far away from the source the amplitude will no longer decrease much unless your figure illustrates the fields over very large distances. It’s all a matter of scale of the figure compared with the scale over which the amplitude decreases noticeably.

In a similar way the gravitational force decreases with distance in the same way as the electric force, but this does not prevent us from considering the gravitation force as pretty much constant near the surface of Earth, even if technically it does vary with altitude and this change can be measured.  Even if you are on the tenth floor of a building, the gravitational force will be basically as if you were on the ground floor, simply because the force does not vary significantly over the height of a building.

Comment: Thank you. So, those pictures are just approximations in the limit of high distances. But the conditions are not always mentioned alongside the picture. I guess some educational websites took it wrong because I have seen some using the same picture as the EM waves emitted from an antenna in its vicinity.

Comment: There is just one more problem. The photon nature of light says that the light source is emitting photons. If you are a point charge with no dimensions, wouldn't the energy you get from those particles be independent of distance from the source just like our sun?? If that's the case, shouldn't the amplitude of the wave be indeed constant?? EM waves theory should be compatible with this, am I right?

Comment: @M.Mahdi: the power you get from the photons depends on the number density of the photons as well as the energy of an "individual" photon, which is the thing that decreases as an inverse square in a photon picture

Answer (score 0):

The amplitude of a wave will decrease if there is absorption of the wave's energy.  This is true for any wave, E&M, sound, etc.  I'm not sure what pictures you see on the internet related to this, but if the E&M wave is propagating through vacuum, then it's amplitude will not decrease.

So what counts as absorption?  For one, the rotational and vibrational modes of molecules will absorb infrared radiation that passes through a gas as long as the E&M wave contains frequencies that excite those modes.  Any substance that can be excited by the E&M wave will act as an absorber.

Waves are described by a wave equation. For E&M waves in a vacuum, the wave equation looks like this:  $$\nabla^2E = \frac{\epsilon_0}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t^2}$$  This equation has no absorption term, and a solution is a wave whose amplitude is constant.  Usually an absorption term shows up as a term related to a single derivative with respect to time.  In E&M waves an absorption term would change the equation to look like:$$\nabla^2E = \frac{\epsilon}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t^2} + \frac{4\pi\sigma}{c^2}\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} $$  The second term on the right leads to a solution that shows absorption.  The sigma in the second term is related in this case to the conductivity of the material the wave is passing through.

Answer (score 0):

No, not the inverse square law.

For a spherical wave:

$$ \vec E(r) \propto \frac{e^{ikr}} r $$

(so $r^{-1}$).

The energy (intensity) in the wave goes as $||E^2||$, so that does fall as $r^{-2}$. The magnetic field's strength is related to the electric field strength, and will show the same behavior.

A plane wave, on the other hand, is constant with $r$:

$$ \vec E(x, y, z) \propto e^{ikx} $$

Of course, a true plane wave must extend to infinity in the transverse directions, which is strictly a mathematical approximation. Any truncation is equivalent to an aperture, and if that is on the order of dimension $d$, the wave will spread diffractively with an angle:

$$ \sin\theta \approx \frac{2\pi}{kd}. $$

Answer (score 0):

> Most of the pictures I see on the internet on electromagnetic waves, show two prependicular constant sinusoidal waves made of electric and magnetic fields.

The representation of electromagnetic waves is taken from solutions of the Maxwell equations , and in general classical electromagnetic radiation follows very well those solutions. The pictures are over a very small number of wavelengths for *one directonal*  waves , and those solutions show no diminution of E and B fields.

When antenna waves are modeled and a three dimensional representation is plotted, the intensity of the radiation  (power in the beam) falls, the further away from the source, but one does not  use  the sine wave diagrams.

The era of quantum mechanics showed experimentally the corpuscular nature of light, composed of photons carrying the energy of the classical electromagnetic waves, and the energy per unit area carried by the photons will follow the geometry of the source. Lasers are the best tools to  have an electromagnetic beam that has small divergence, thus immitate the usual polarized plots found in the literature. Still there is a [divergence](https://www.gentec-eo.com/blog/laser-beam-divergence-measurement) .

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the constant sinusoidal waves have constant amplitude and constant wavelength.  Obviously, there should be changes in “constants” when there are power supply changes for production of em waves.  So, pictures assume that the power supply is uniform for production of em waves.  Pictures may assume many things.  It should be noticed that there is no practical simultaneous combined observation of both electric field wave and magnetic field wave.  It happens because when both types of waves are propagated they need not be a combined one.  Light waves are electric field waves, and radio waves are magnetic field waves.  In Hertz experiment, both light waves and radio waves occur, but they are independent.  There are three cases: (1) No wave occurs, but oscillations for both fields may happen; (2) Only one field oscillation may become wave propagation; (3) Both fields may become independent wave propagations.